# Save email to outlook folder using ActiveXObject or Office Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, c#, outlook, outlook-redemption, activexobject

In outlook, there is a feature “Home page address” of folder through which we can view web site within the outlook. If we set http://app.abctest.com in the Home page address of a folder, then when we click this folder in the outlook, it will display that page.

I have a very specific requirement for enabling end user to browse a web site (in my case, it basically lists some archived emails) within from the Outlook. This can be easily done by setting the “Home page address” in the properties windows of any Folder of Outlook.

The user will see the page within outlook. He can search the old archived emails in the page.  Then, the users should be able to download that email and save it to a folder in outlook. End users are basically searching the emails within outlook and downloading them from the server directly to their outlook folder. When user click the download\save link or button, then the outlook’s “Select Folder” dialog should appear where user can select the destination folder. When user click “OK” button, that email should be save to the selected folder in the outlook.

Currently, I have very few solutions but not sure if they can achieve the goal.

**Solution 1: ActiveXObject**

I tried to use Outlook ActiveXObject in javascript (used the following code in my test page) but I got the following Script error Popup message.

***“Automation server cannot create the object”.*** 
Javascript code:
  var objO = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');

**Solution 2: Javascript API for Office**

I have started to read the MSDN documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142185.aspx but have not got any sample code.

Could someone please sheds some light on it? Or what would be the best solution for this? Or any alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Prakash,

Only one instance of Outlook can be run at the same time. Try to use the [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7tf9xwsc(v=vs.94).aspx) function instead to get the running Outlook instance instead. See [How to programmatically create an Outlook home folder page in the Outlook Today style](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28351/How-to-programmatically-create-an-Outlook-home-fol) for more information. However, home page scripting is limited and secured to prevent malicious software. I'd suggest developing an add-in which can add a custom form instead.

The second solution listed above is for Mail Apps. See [How to: Create your first mail app for Outlook by using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142159.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Regarding add-in, we do not want to develop add-in because we want to develop a solution where user would have to do very minimal like installation\uninstallation and version update. And next major point is, we already have a site where it provides search facility of archived emails.   
I will check your other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When your script runs inside a folder home page, window.external.OutlookApplication will point to an instance off the Outlook.Application object - your should be able to use it without creating a new object.